# Parameters used by the optimizer query

Tags: oracle

I vaguely remember that I need to join the two weird tables to get an output of all the parameters like this:

```
OPTIMIZER_MODE/GOAL = Choose
_OPTIMIZER_PERCENT_PARALLEL = 101
HASH_AREA_SIZE = 131072
HASH_JOIN_ENABLED = TRUE
HASH_MULTIBLOCK_IO_COUNT = 0
SORT_AREA_SIZE = 65536
...
```

This is an output from 10053, but I don't have OS access to get full trace (and get parameters as a sideffect). I need sql query.

Comment: No need to *shout* in the title. We are not deaf and your question is not more special than the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from v$parameter2 order by name;
```

This will show all regular parameter values for the session but only the hidden parameter values that are different than the default.

Comment: This is even better than the query that I had in mind. Who in the right mind may remember all these cryptic X$ names?